# Wi-fi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 Acer Aspire E1-431

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless, acer

Wifi is not available in network settings.
Wifi hot key is not working.

[image]

Result of

`rfkill list`                           -> no result

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`             -> no result

```
sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.2
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.2
       logical name: enp4s0f2
       version: 0a
       serial: 08:9e:01:8e:6f:16
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:90404000-90404fff memory:90400000-90403fff
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: It looks like wifi is disabled in bios or broken. There is a small chance that it is a built-in USB device. look into `lsusb`.